# Frequency Distribution Test Vs. Chi Square Goodness of FIt

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, histogram, degrees-of-freedom, frequency

I need to prove that the higher frequency of an occurrence within a particular range is statistically significant.  Let me explain this with an example:

X-axis has ages and Y-axis has the frequencies of humans sleeping more than 10 hours a day.
I need to prove that people below 10 years and above 80 years of age sleep more than 10 hours a day compared to those in other age groups (such as 10-20 yrs, 20-30,.... 50-60, etc.).  A simple histogram can show you higher frequency but then each group also has different universe size.  So something like hitrate might not be statistically correct.

I have looked into `Chi-Square Goodness of Fit` test but I'm not sure what a good choice of `expected frequency` would be in this case.  Can you suggest the right approach to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can't *prove*  this with statistics, you can just offer evidence.

That said, I would look into regression models. Given that you want to show something about specific ages, you could use a model like this:

$Y = b_0 + b_1\mathrm{age} + b2(\mathrm{age}<10) + b3(\mathrm{age}> 80)$

But that would not say anything about 10 hours, specifically. If you want to look at that exact number then you could do a crosstab table of "slept over 10 hours" (yes/no) vs. "between 10 and 80 years old" (yes/no) and then do a chi-square test.